# When information in trailer in frame and when checksum errors in tcp segment

Tags: tcp, frame, switch-statement, checksum, data-link-layer

I'm studying for my exam 'ComputerNetworking'. I have two questions:
- when does a trailer in a frame (link-layer network) contain information?
- when can TCP-segments have checksum errors?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Trailer example: AAL5 (Asynchronous Transfer Mode aka ATM)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATM_Adaptation_Layer_5

But many link layer protocols don't have any or maybe just the CRC checksum if that's considered as trailer.

TCP checksum is for error checking of TCP header and data.